# Iterable String

Tags: python, string, iterator

So knowing what an iterator is, I'm assumign a string is an iterable object because the following is possible:

```
for c in str:
  print c
```

I am subclassing `str` and overriding `__hash__` and `__eq__`. In `__hash__`, I am trying to iterate over the string as follows:

```
for c in self.__str__:
```

The following error however returns: `TypeError: 'method-wrapper' object is not iterable`. This means that `__str__` is not iterable. How do I get an iterable version of the string? I tried looking up some sort of `str` object API on Python but Python's documentation only shows you how to use a string, and not what the internals are, and which object in `str` is iterable.

How can I iterate through my subclassed string, within my string object?

Comment: Of course a method object is not iterable. And you trying to iterate over one: - `__str__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`__str__` is another hook method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__), and not the value of the string.

If this is a subclass of `str`, you can just iterate over `self` instead:

```
for c in self:
```

or you can make it more explicit:

```
for c in iter(self):
```

If this is *not* a subclass, perhaps you meant to *call* `__str__()`:

```
for c in self.__str__():
```

or you can avoid calling the hook and use `str()`:

```
for c in str(self):
```

Comment: Got it, So just a question, I find Python's documentation page terrible. Where can I find the `str` object doc page? Not the page that teaches me how to use a string, but the actual doc page with all the methods etc...

Comment: @Darksky: Look for the standard types page: [`str` is part of the sequence types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange), with an additional [`str` specific methods section](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) below it.

Answer (score 3):

Just `for c in self` should do. Since `self` is a string, you get iteration over the characters.

`for c in self.__str__` does not work, because `__str__` is a method, which you'd have to call (but that's useless in this case).

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly need to call the `__str__` hook, you can either call it by `str(self)` (recommended), or `self.__str__()` (not recommended, as a matter of style).

`self.__str__` just refers to the method object of that name, rather than calling it.